# React Native iOS app delay between clicking app icon and opening app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-hermes

I made a react native application but when I try to open it on an iPhone 13 Mini, it has a delay of about a second before opening the app.

It's not universal on other devices, I tried on Android but then there is no delay. Also on an iPhone 8, without any delay.

I tried using Hermes as I read it will speed up the bundling of the app. It did speed it up a bit, but I still experience a delay.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Hi! I'm experiencing the same thing. There is a delay between the moment I click the icon and the moment the splash screen appears. During that delay the icon status is "clicked" (darker). Did you manage to fix it?